# Isn't Flora's ability inefficient?

Tags: claymore

I've been watching Claymore. I haven't read the manga yet.

Number 8, Flora:

> She's the fastest there is at unsheathing, slashing, and sheathing back her claymore.

[image]

As you can see, she unsheathes, slashes, and sheathes back so fast that the image of her hand seems to be static, whereas a bunch of slashes appear around the target.

But wait.

**What is the *point* of sheathing her claymore back while attacking someone?** Isn't that a waste of time? Wouldn't it be more useful to unsheathe and then slash countless times rather than sheathing back her claymore during a fight?

**Proof that she's indeed sheathing after X amount of slashes**:

This scene below lasts for **several seconds**. This means that she must continuously sheathe her claymore, otherwise this image effect wouldn't be possible:
[image]

Comment: would not call it counterproductive, also can you provide any reference she really sheathes her sword after each slash?
because she could also unsheathe, slash, slash, [...], sheathe (and as far as i understood it is that way)

Comment: @Vogel612: There, I've found a reference, and also modified the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's actually a fencing style based entirely on the drawing of the sword called [Iaijutsu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iaijutsu). For a reference, the [Ukyo Tachibana character from the game, "Samurai Shodown"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSzEACull7A) uses this technique, drawing the sword as a form of attack and re-sheathing the blade all in one move. There is also [Iaido](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iaid%C5%8D), "a modern Japanese martial art associated with the smooth, controlled movements of drawing the sword from its scabbard or saya, striking or cutting an opponent, removing blood from the blade, and then replacing the sword in the scabbard." Though in practice, the Iaido isn't a super fast movement. But again, the emphasis is on the sheathed sword being a starting point, so in order to perform another move, the sword has to be re-sheathed.

The Iaijutsu article mentions that there is two postures for executing the technique, the standing position or the kneeling position, but both involve the sword being sheathed and using the drawing of the sword as a strike. Obviously, there's no real world instance of someone doing this as fast as Flora, but the technique is that the starting point of the strike is from a sheathed sword.

Other well known users of this technique (though not necessarily the only technique that is used):

- [Goemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goemon_Ishikawa_XIII) (Lupin III)
- [Himura Kenshin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himura_Kenshin) (Rurouni Kenshin)
- [Ginkaku Uneri](http://katanagatari.wikia.com/wiki/Ginkaku_Uneri) (Katanagatari)
- Honoka (The Third)

Comment: Do you know if in the manga they talk about Flora's fencing style?

Comment: @Omega they talk about it as the "[Windcutter](http://claymore.wikia.com/wiki/Windcutter)" and go into a bit of detail about how it works, but I don't recall ever explaining why such a technique was used. There's definitely no mention of "Iaijutsu" or anything like that in the manga as far as I recall.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/claymore/comments/3lybqh/technique_talk_tuesdays_windcutter/)'s a similar discussion on Reddit, though from some of the images from the manga it doesn't seem like it's a requirement of Windcutter to return the claymore to its sheath after each strike. Flora's Windcutter technique definitely drew inspiration from Iaijutsu in real life [as Jon said](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4244/8486), but I think there is also an in-universe explanation<sup>*</sup>, though about that of a different technique, that may be applicable to Windcutter.

<sup>* I say an in-universe explanation because I don't know of the practicality of the theory in real life.</sup>

In volume 12 of the manga,

> Riful of the West figured out the reason Rachel was doing her weird battle stance was to empower her attacks with increased speed and strength:
>
>  [image: Rachel "complimenting" Riful for the first time]
>
>  Then a number of pages later, Rachel flaunted a variation of her [technique](https://claymore.fandom.com/wiki/Strong_Sword) that is usable mid-air with what I interpret to be the help of a comrade's claymore providing the necessary friction:
>
>   [image: Rachel teaching Riful a lesson 1]
>   [image: Rachel teaching Riful a lesson 2]

This essentially works the same as Seigen Irako's Mumyou Sakanagare from *Shigurui*,

> [image: True Mumyou Sakanagare technique]
>
>  where in the image on the right is Irako having perfected his technique that he could use it with the friction provided by his toes.

So what the user of the Windcutter technique might benefit from redrawing her claymore from the sheath with each subsequent attack is increased speed and strength provided by the friction with the innards of the scabbard. What I find spectacular is how the scabbard doesn't break down from the repetitively fast sheathing and unsheathing of the claymore. Anyways, I believe this is also one of the reasons why [the Windcutter has more strength than the Quicksword](https://claymore.fandom.com/wiki/Windcutter#Comparison_between_the_Windcutter_and_the_Quicksword) despite being slower and using less concentrated yoma energy, at least at the time of the Northern Campaign.